# Updating to another Database with a lengthy IN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update

I'm trying to update certain columns from one DB to another in tables whose `Id` columns align.

I have the query below, but I fear it will update all rows because the IN clause values aren't being matched.

How do I match all those values within the IN clause to the relevant column from Table1?  Or is this correct as is?

```
UPDATE Table1
SET NAME = T2.Name
FROM OTHERDB.[Table2] as T2
WHERE T2.Id in
(
'12345678'
 --...
}
```

Comment: Please add the tag of the DB you are using to your question.

Comment: which dbms are you using? also this update doesn't work in any sql engines

Comment: I'm using SSMS.

Comment: @John, SSMS is the tool used to interface with the database.  The DBMS you are using is SQL Server, right?

Comment: Yes I'm using SQL Server

Comment: Do the ID columns match between DBs? If not, how are the rows matched?

Comment: Yes they do.  They should match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicions are correct: your query will update every row.

You need a join:

```
UPDATE T1
SET NAME = T2.Name
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN OTHERDB.Table2 as T2 ON T2.Id = T1.Id
WHERE T1.Id in (
    '12345678',
     ...
}
```

This assumes that `Id` columns match up between databases. If that’s not the case, the join/where clauses would need adjustment.

Using an inner join means if there’s no corresponding data in the other database, there won’t be an update to null.

The `where` clause now looks up on the local table’s `Id` for efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.Name = T2.Name 
FROM OtherDB.Table2 T2 
WHERE T2.Id IN 
(
   SELECT Id FROM Table1 (NOLOCK) WHERE ...
)
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand says [**Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere**](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)